# jquery datepicker function modification

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can i modify this function to change the value of #datepicker2 to #datepicker1's date plus one day if the date of #datepicker1 is after the date of #datepicker2?

So if the default dates for #datepicker1 and #datepicker two are 11/03/2011 and 11/04/2011 respectively and i change #datepicker1 to 11/25/2011, #datepicker2 should be populated with 11/26/2011.

But if i change #datepicker1 to, say, 10/28/2011 #datepicker2 remains unchanged.

Heres a jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/hJrzp/1/

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({
     //   minDate:  new Date(),
    //    maxDate: '+2y',
        defaultDate: "+1d",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
    //    changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "datepicker1" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can we simplify this question to say that the requirement is that when `datepicker1` changes, `datepicker2` is set to `datepicker1` date plus one day? Is that an accurate statement or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add one day when the datepicker is the first one (i.e. `#datepicker1`). This involves some date arithmetic. So, the `onSelect` function would look like:

```
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var option = this.id == "datepicker1" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings );
        if (this.id == 'datepicker1') {
            var oneDay = 1000*60*60*24;
            var plusOneDay = new Date(date.getTime() + oneDay);
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, plusOneDay );
        } else {
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    }
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/hJrzp/2/.